# Saving cell Presets in a dropdown list

Tags: vba, excel

At the moment I have created a spreadsheet which takes a bunch of inputs, runs them through a list of formulas, and then spits out the results onto a "report" worksheet.

I've been manually saving each of these reports as separate CSVs but I was hoping for a better method moving forward as it is getting quite tiring to have to open 10 CSVs when i do my monthly reports.

I am looking for a way to start saving all of these reports into a "database". My hope to to have one cell be for an user entry name and for two buttons. One to save the current report under the name entered by the user, and two to remove old records. I would then be able to revisit old entries by selecting them in the dropdown.

I've dabbled with VBA and Macros in the past but this is a little more complicated than what I've dealt with in the past. Looking for some help/direction.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Please provide sample data showing what your data looks like, and what your desired result is. Suggestion: consider organizing all of the "reports" into separate tabs of one workbook, or possibly, into a separate "reports" workbook which is manipulated by the main workbook. That way you don't have to open all these separate files and tabs of that workbook can then be exported as .csv, .pdf, etc... to produce reports.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your reports need to be used, you might find it satisfactory to simply make your data into one big Excel Table ( **Insert Tab > Table** ). When you do this, Excel will automatically fill-down any formulas that you enter in a column, and also show the formula using the headers instead of A1-style references.

[image]

I use this format, adding Y under Remove from Active List on each line that is already done.  Then whenever I save the file or look at it for today's status, I filter out what's old and just look at the new.  The other filters enable copy-pasting or printing whatever arrangement I like.

[image]

The filters and other things in the table can be referenced in VBA as Sheets("ThisSheet").ListObjects(1), which is an object with a number of useful properties and methods.

For VBA information, read more here: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables

This is my code for auto-filtering the table to hide inactive items at time of save.  You add it at ThisWorkbook in the VBA editor:

[image]

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
SelectedCell = ActiveCell.Address 'this saves your screen selection for after the filtering
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range(1, 1).Select
If ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).AutoFilter.FilterMode = True Then
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Item(1).AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End If
A = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range.Rows(1).Find("Remove from List").Column - _
  ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range.Column + 1
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter field:=A, Criteria1:="="
Range(SelectedCell).Select

End sub
```

Comment: Use **Data Tab > Data Validation > From List** to make whatever dropdown you like... I put these on a separate sheet.

Comment: The Table is already setup to make a PivotTable... just go to **Insert Tab > PivotTable**.